# How is the python floor division operator implemented?

Tags: python, python-3.x, precision, floor-division

I know how the // operator works, but what is going on behind the scenes?

What I really want to know: Is it subject to floating point precision errors even when operating exclusively on integers?

Comment: I pretty sure there are no concerns for precision errors when exclusively using integers... in that `x == (x//n)*n + x%n` will always hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python does not use floating point arithmetic when calculating `a // b` (for a, b integers). An implementation of the classical long division algorithm to calculate the quotient and remainder when dividing `a` and `b`.

The actual division for large integers is implemented in `x_divrem()` which is found in [longobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c).

Answer (score 0):

This is a C implementation of Python floor division (when `b` is positive):

```
int py_floor_div(int a, int b)
{
    if (a >= 0)
        return a / b;
    return (a - b + 1) / b;
}
```